# Run an application via shortcut using Process.Start()

Tags: c#, shortcut

Is there a way to run an application via shortcut from a C# application?

I am attempting to run a .lnk from my C# application. The shortcut contains a significant number of arguments that I would prefer the application not have to remember.

Attempting to run a shortcut via `Process.Start()` causes an exception.

> Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid Win32 application

This is the code I am using.

```cs
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo ( "example.lnk" );
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
Process whatever = Process.Start( info );
```

Comment: The shortcut requires arguments or is it the target of the shortcut that requires arguments?

Comment: @Jodrell updated with requested info.  The target of the shortcut requires arguments.

Comment: Make sure the shortcut actually works - it could be broken.

Comment: @Charles the shortcut does work.  It points to a bat file - I can run the bat file and the shortcut via point-and-click.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Setting `UseShellExecute = false` was the problem.  Once I removed that, it stopped crashing.

Comment: This is even more important now because .NET core has changed the default of this property to false. I was running into this when I wasn't setting this property at all.

Answer (score 18):

Could you post some code. Something like this should work:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\myShortcut.lnk";
proc.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

if your file is EXE or another file type like ".exe" or ".mkv" or ".pdf" and you want run that with shortcut link your code must like this.


i want run "Translator.exe" program.

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Users\alireza\Desktop\Translator.exe.lnk");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using UseShellExecute = false and trying to launch a batch file make sure to add .bat to the end of the filename. You don't need .bat if UseShellExecute = true though. This made me just waste an hour of work... hoping to save someone else.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for helping. Taking the [tour] will get you your first badge. Have fun.

Comment: I don't understand. Why would you leave off the file extension?