# c# start menu style listbox

Tags: c#, listview, startmenu, installed-applications

Hey everyone I am working on a start menu style program and would like to know how I get pinned programs  and all programs list. I started some research and will post what I found so you can all help fill the gaps.

For getting program icons I found this...

```
public static Icon IconFromFilePath(string filePath)
{
    var result = (Icon)null;

    try
    {
        result = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath);
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        // swallow and return nothing. You could supply a default Icon here as well
    }

    return result;
}
```

For getting all programs and pinned programs I find these paths...

%USERPROFILE%\appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\

*What are these locations and how does the startmenu utlise these?* How can I use them? Hope I am not being to brief but wanted to show I am really working to solve this problem and have been searching a ton. Thanks!

Comment: What are you asking here? The start menu displays the contents of those folders in a specific way (on the "All Programs" and "pinned" lists). Nothing really special going on. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Sure I will try, in short I want to know how I myself can recreate the "pinned" and "All Programs" lists.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like you already have the info you need. What are you missing?

Comment: I don't exactly know how to implement this, I found what I stated above but find myself confused. Still not sure how I can make a list of pinned and all programs just like you see in start menu. Question is how I do that... sorry im confusing. I will make clear, how I make a start menu list.

Comment: Also it appears they are checking both the users and global system start menu folders and displaying both "-" the duplicates. But still doesn't explain where the pins are coming from.

Comment: You can get the pinned list from here: http://superuser.com/questions/171096/where-is-the-list-of-pinned-start-menu-and-taskbar-items-stored-in-windows-7 Stack overflow isn't for writing entire programs, could you be more specific as to what you are struggling with?

Comment: Dude your awsome and have answered 50% of my question now. Now all I need to know is how I can get those shortcuts in a listbox that I can click to open app. Feel free to move your above comment with link to answers. Also please vote for my thread.

Comment: This question is still very broad. I'll give you an upvote, because I'm on the fence, but try to reign in the scope of your questions a bit in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, you can get the list of pinned programs for a user using:

> %AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User
>   Pinned\StartMenu

Credit to https://superuser.com/a/171129

Both that folder, and the ones you already found, contain all the shortcuts for the Start Menu. You can get the files using `Directory.EnumerateFiles` or `Directory.GetFiles`. Once you have the list of files, you'll need to create ViewModel objects for each of them:

```
public class StartMenuItem
{
    public Image Icon {get; set;}
    public String LinkPath {get; set;}
}
```

Create a collection of these and bind your list view `ItemSource` to it. Finally, to start the application, you can just use `Process.Start`:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo ( "example.lnk" );
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
Process whatever = Process.Start( info );
```

See [Run application via shortcut using Process.Start C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141821/run-application-via-shortcut-using-process-start-c-sharp) for more information.

Comment: Note, I did not post the `DataTemplate` as my answer was already pretty long. If you have a question about how to bind to images in a template, or how to set up the command to run the `Process.Start`, I would ask another question about that piece.

Comment: Thank You! This is just what I needed I will make a thread if I need more help with process.start but think I understand it.