# is it possible open an .exe file using wpf openfiledialog

Tags: c#, wpf

shortcut has been created for some windows application like paint under a folder under my documents and all i wanted to do is to invoke these applications with a click event handler of a button.
my code as follow:

```
   Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\SomeTestFolder";
        //openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        //openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        // Insert code to read the stream here.
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

as you could see this currently open a folder with the short cut on it my question is how do I tweak this to enable me when I click on any short cut an application should launch ?
thank you in advance

Comment: Use the OpenFileDialog to get the **pathname** of the exe and then pass that to `Process.Start`.

Comment: I'm sorry if you think it is a duplicate.  I do believe it is not as I do not want to directly open the path of exe as I mentioned above in my explanation I have created a folder in which I have created a short cut to the exe file within that folder so when I click on openfiledialog I should be able to select the short cut of the exe then select it and click open then the exe should launch. Cause all the Process.Start () launch the exe from it is physical location not through a short cut . Correct if I'm wrong and if my method is not worth trying

Comment: I think you are referring to the following code: Process  proc = new Proces ();

Comment: See this answer for running a shortcut - http://stackoverflow.com/a/23358242/59303

Comment: this what i have done for those who will come across this post: create variables `//variable that get the windows directory
        static string windir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");

        //variable that point to accessories shortcuts folder
       static string shortcutsFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("shortcutFolder"); `

Comment: this what i have done : create variables `//variable that point to accessories shortcuts folder
       static string shortcutsFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("shortcutFolder"); ` then on App.config: `<appSettings>   <add key="shortcutFolder"value="C:\Library Test"/>
    </appSettings>`finally on the button event handler: `private static void btnMovie_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string MovieMaker = shortcutsFolder + "\\MovieMaker";
            StartProcess.ProcessMethod(MovieMaker);
        }`