# how to click on a desktop icon (URL shortcut icon created in the desktop by the user) and open that?

Tags: c#, click, desktop

i created a desktop icon (shortcut) for a URL (lets say a google.com shortcut on my desktop), so that when i click on it , IE opens and launches google.com website.

is there anyway to program the second part ?
i am looking for the code to just click on that shortcut and somehow launch that page .
thanks

Comment: How is this a coding question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141821/run-application-via-shortcut-using-process-start-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run application via shortcut using Process.Start C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141821/run-application-via-shortcut-using-process-start-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Process.Start("cmd", @"/c %UserProfile%\Desktop\fileName.ext");
```

This will open `cmd.exe`(command prompt) and pass the `/c` arguement to it followed by a command.  This essentially executes the command followed by `/c`.

Doing this will essentially do the same thing as double-clicking on the file.